# Scaling background images to fill browser window with centering and aspect ratio

Tags: css, image, background, scaling, aspect-ratio

I know there is a lot of information out there on this but I've searched and searched and still have not found the help that I need.

Essentially I'm trying to fill the entire browser window with a background image that scales itself and retains it's aspect ratio automatically at any size so that it can be viewed on any device.

Here is an excellent example of what I am trying to achieve:

http://www.comme-des-garcons.com/rawvision.html

The background image, when sized to 320x480 then stretched from 480 to 640 expands itself to the right!

If anyone out there can shed some light on how this is achieved via css I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: wow , that site is rather interesting and a bit cnofusing . hmm cool stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the new CSS3 property `background-size: cover`

You can see it with this fiddle I created http://fiddle.jshell.net/rxMbe/

Example:

```
body{
  background-image: url(splash.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

It is widely supported by all major browsers, it's safe to use: http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts

Comment: Expanding the background image to the right to make up for the proportion when stretched length wise is effect I'm looking for... Sadly the background-size: cover; does not achieve this.

Comment: Wow! well you've got it to work on fiddle! I've been messing with the background-size: cover; property for hours and it wont work for me... My images will either repeat itself on the bottom or with no-repeat the background color can be seen..

Comment: Here is the CSS I'm using:                                                                      body {background-color:#102008;} 

body {background-image:url("../images/bg1.jpg"); background-size: cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;}

Comment: Got it! Just need to add the:                                         html, body{height: 100%; width: 100%;} To the top of my CSS document... Now I just have to find away to get rid of those scroll bars!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by giving `min-width` and `min-height` to 100%

Wrap this image inside a div.

```
<div><img src="images/bg.jpg" id="bg" alt=""></div>
```

here is the CSS should be.

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 

  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If you are using image as a background. you should try this. 

`background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;`

Comment: Got my answer! Thanks for your help though!